# Multivariate limit existence as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> $f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> x \sin{\frac{1}{y}},  & \text{$y \ne 0$} \\
> 0, & \text{$y=0$}
> \end{cases}$
>
> Study the following limits: $$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} {f(x,y)}$$
>   $$\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} {f(x,y)}$$
>   $$\lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} {f(x,y)}$$

The limit $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} {f(x,y)}=0$ (as it is $0$ on both cases), and the limit $\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

However, doing an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof for the limit $\lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} {f(x,y)}$ shows that it exists and it is equal to $0$.

My question is, since the limit $\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} {f(x,y)}$ doesn't exist, shouldn't this be an indicator that the limit $\lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} {f(x,y)}$ doesn't exist?

(Are there any other examples for similarly tricky situations?)

Comment: Squeeze..

$$-1 \le \sin(1/y) \le 1 \implies -x \le x \sin(1/y) \le x$$

Now what can you say? Also, by your definition of $f$ in the question, the limit as $y \to 0$ does exist.

Comment: As @Mattos wrote, the $sin$ function is bounded and $x\rightarrow 0$...

Comment: What should be a indicator that the limit doesn't exist is the limit $\lim_{y\to 0} f(0,y)$ (fixing $x=0$ because path has to pass through  $(0,0)$), and it is equal $0$.

Answer (score 2):

> and the limit $\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

**Wrong**.

The correct version would be:

> If $x\neq 0$, the limit $\lim_{y\to0} f(x,y)$ does not exist.

For $x=0$, the limit is equal to $$\lim_{y\to 0} 0\cdot\sin\frac1y$$

and this limit is clearly equal to $0$.

Comment: Oops, my bad. But doesn't the fact that the limit $\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} {f(x,y)}$ doesn't exist, automatically make the $\lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} {f(x,y)}$ not exist? Aren't we approaching the origin from a direction in that way?

Comment: @zeropancakes that would only be true if the limit did not exist for y=0

Comment: Did you mean for x=0?

Comment: @zeropancakes yes, of course. Sorry.

Comment: @zeropancakes you can still conclude that the function is not continuous on (x, 0) for nonzero values of x, of course

Comment: But how is it not continuous? Don't we have $\lim _{x \rightarrow 5} {f(x,0)}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 5} {0}=0=f(5,0)$ ?

Comment: Nevermind, we need $\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} {f(5,y)}$ to be equal to $0$ also but it doesn't exist

Comment: I actually don't know anymore I'm kind of confused..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66930/discussion-between-zeropancakes-and-5xum).

Comment: @ZeroPancakes Exactly, if $f$ is continuous a $(5,0)$, then $\lim_{y\to 0} f(5,y)$ must be equal to $f(5,0)$, but it is not.